# Hook activation problems

Tags: php, wordpress

I am doing a project and I have a problem that I can not solve. I need to display an HTML code when the administrator of my WordPress site publishes a page or a post.

I have in my code used the hook [edit_form_after_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_form_after_title/) to realize that but the HTML code does not appear at all. I also used the hook [edit_form_after_editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_form_after_editor/) to see if the problem did not come from but unfortunately without success.

PHP code is here:

```
add_action('edit_form_after_title', array($this, 'postEditActionExecute'));
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'../assets/views/socialCommentClient.php');
```

Unfortunately I tried to find solutions and looked at the list of available hooks but I didn't find anything.

Your help would be valuable :) Thank you!

Comment: So, you want to display some HTML element after the title in the Editor or is it that you want to display something when the admin actually publishes a page or post?

Comment: Also, is your site using the Classic Editor or the new Block (Gutenberg) Editor?

Comment: Please post the code for the function postEditActionExecute.